# Why iOS on iPhones and iPads automatically end an app (ie Youtube) after idling? Is there a way to stop iOS from ending apps when idling?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, youtube

It's terribly frustrating to have watched parts of a Youtube video, then have iOS quit it. Unless I wrote down the time-stamp, I would have no idea where I left off. Is there a way to stop iOS from ending apps when idling? Thank you!

Comment: Huh. When I watch a YouTube video the app tracks where I am even between multiple devices.

Comment: I've never had that happen. See [ask] for tips on asking good questions here. To prevent your question from being down voted or closed, add additional info such as the iOS version, device, app being used, etc. Right now you're not giving us much to go by to help troubleshoot.

Comment: You’re missing lots of detail here.   Are you using the native iOS YouTube app or a browser?  If a browser, which one?  What version of iOS are you running?  Is this with only YouTube or all media.?

Comment: This is by default. If you want to watch/listen continuously in the background you might have to purchase Youtube Red https://www.youtube.com/premium

Answer (score 1):

iOS automatically quits apps which haven't been used for some time, especially if available memory required for the active apps runs low. There is no setting to disable that (which probably wouldn't be a good idea anyway as it would block other apps from getting loaded/started).

But usually apps get notified before they get unloaded and are supposed to store their current state (including for instance the playback position for YouTube) so they can restore it when you switch back to them/restart them. If you need advice on how to make this work for you when using YouTube, please ask a *new* question (and include the details others asked for in the comments).